# netcat windows listen for password on UDP

Tags: windows, cmd, udp, netcat

I want to use netcat to open a listener on an UDP port using netcat (any other tool is welcome as well, but it's the one I have found to be useful for now), which is listening for a password to be entered to execute another action.

Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work as desired:

`ncat.exe -kluvp 4444 -c "set /P pwd=pwd: & if %pwd%==pwd (echo yes) else (echo no)`

But when I connect from the client, `ncat -4u -w1 localhost 4444`, with whatever I write as input I get yes, but it should only print yes when I write pwd.

Comment: As it's a BASH command why are you asking about CMD.

Comment: Because I know I can do it in bash, but I need it on CMD because the machine I have to use it on works on Windows, not linux.

Comment: What would Windows experts know about unix? You are not asking a Windows' question.

Comment: I am not asking a windows expert to translate the command, I am asking a windows expert if she knows if a command exists that is able to do what I am asking in the first paragraph: Launch an ncat listener on UDP that is waiting for a password and if it is correct, execute an action.
The BASH command is only an example that I know it works, and so that any windows expert who knows some bash knows exactly what the command does.

Comment: Please regard that this site is not a free translation service, so you have to try it on your own! Come back here when you are facing a problem and ask a specific question then, providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have edited the question with my results so far.